# Exclude other methods, variables and classes that are not needed for your method to work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

You load a foreign code example with libraries attached to it in Visual Studio. Now there is a method that you want to reuse in your code. Is there a function in VS that lets you strip the code from all unnecessary code to only have code left that is necessary for your current method to run?

It is not about the library. Loading a .sln or .csproj and having classes over classes when you just want one method out of it is a waste of performance, ram and space. It is about code you can easily omit or references(what I call libraries) you can easily omit. A part-question of this is: Which "using" statement do you need that is only necessary for your current method and the methods that pass paramaters to it? In short, showing relevant code only. Code that is tied to each other.

Let's use an example: You go to github and download source code in c#. Let's call the solution S. You open S in Visual Studio. You don't disassemble, you just load the source code of S, that is there in plain text. Then you find a method M - in plain text - that you want to use. M contains some objects whose classes were defined somewhere in the project. The goal is to recreate the surrounding only for this method to copy & paste it into my own solution without having red underlined words in almost every line within the method

Comment: I do not understand what you try to achieve? Why you care there is more in the library?

Comment: @Aldert It is not about the library. Loading a .sln or .csproj and having classes over classes when you just want one method out of it is a waste of performance, ram and space. It is about code you can easily omit or references(what I call libraries) you can easily omit. A part-question of this is: Which "using" statement do you need that is only necessary for your current method and the methods that pass paramaters to it? In short, showing relevant code only. Code that is tied to each other.

Comment: An interesting read: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/30

Answer (score 0):

after reading the question and the comments, I think I have a vague idea what you are referring to.

In case we ignore the context of the method you are referring, you can extract any code piece from a "library" by using a .NET decompiler and assembly browser.

There are many of them for free, such as:

- dotPeek,
- ILSpy
- ...

This will allow you to see the method's code. From there on, you can proceed as you like. In case your copy the method to your code base, you might still have to change it a bit in order to adapt it to work with your objects and context. If you don't, this will give you insight on how the method works and might help you to understand the logic, so you can write your own.

**Disclaimer**: With this post, I am pointing out that it is possible to extract code from an assembly. I am not discussing the ethics or legal perspective behind such actions.

Hope this helps, 
Happy Coding!

Comment: I am surprised how misunderstood this simple issue can be. Alright, let's use an example: You go to github and download source code in c#. Let's call the solution S. You open S in Visual Studio. You don't disassemble, you just load the source code of S, that is there in plain text. Then you find a method M - in plain text - that you want to use. M contains some objects whose classes were defined somewhere in the project. The goal is to recreate the surrounding only for this method to copy & paste it into my own solution without having red underlined words in almost every line within the method

Comment: Ok, I got it now! Sorry that I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

If it`s just one method, look at the source code and copy it to your libarary. Make sure you make a comment where you obtained the code and who has the copyright! Don't forget to include the licence, which you should have done with a libary reference anyway.

That said it is currently not (official) possible to automaticly remove unused public declared code from a library (assembly). This process is called Treeshaking by the way. Exception: .NET Native.

But .NET Native is only available for Windows Store Apps. You can read more about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/09/the-net-native-tool-chain/).

That said, we have the JIT (Just in Time)-Compiler which is realy smart. I wouldn't worry about a few KB library code. Spend your time optimizing your SQL Queries and other bottlenecks. The classes are only loaded, [when you actualy use them](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/308603/122683).

Using some unstable solutions or maintaining a fork of a library, where you use more then one method (with no documentation and no expertise, since it is your own fork) isn't worth the headache, you will have!

---

If you realy want to go the route of removing everything you do not want, you can open the solution, declare everything as `internal` (search and replace is your friend) and restore the parts to public, which are giving you are Buildtime error / Runtime error (Reflection). Then remove everything which is internal. There are several DesignTime tools like Resharper, which can remove Dead Code.

But as I said, it's not worth it!

---

For .NET Core users, in [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/292385), we have the [.NET IL Linker](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/30) as [spender has commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53131657/exclude-other-methods-variables-and-classes-that-are-not-needed-for-your-method#comment93167632_53131657), it looks promising. What does this mean? The .NET framework evolves from time to time. Let it envolve and look at your productivity in the meantime.